# Symfony2: Open PDF file in browser

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

In my Symfony 2 project, I would like to display a pdf in the browser when the user clicks on a link for viewing a pdf file. The pdf files are contained in my "views" folder, in a subfolder called "pdf-files".

How do I need to adapt the following controller function so that a pdf file gets displayed in the browser?

```
/**
 * @Route("/pdf/{pdfFilename}")
*/
public function pdfAction($pdfFilename) {
   return $this->render('@App/pdf-files/'.$pdfFilename);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's all about conten-type header of http request. So just set it:

```
$response = $this->render('@App/pdf-files/'.$pdfFilename);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

return $response;
```

Answer (score 3):

To serve static file you might want to use [BinaryFileResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html) class. In such response you can set `content disposition` - is this file should be opened in a browser or downloaded as an attachment.

So your code should look something like:

```
public function pdfAction($pdfFilename)
{
   $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
   $path = $kernel->locateResource('@AppBundle/Resources/pdf-files/'.$pdfFilename);

   $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path)

   $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
   $response->setContentDisposition(
      ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE, //use ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT to save as an attachement
      $pdfFilename
   );

   return $response;
}
```

**EDIT:** since [locateResource](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/Kernel.php#L211) is looking for files under `Resources` directory by default I would suggest moving your `pdf-files` directory from `views` directory to `Resources`

Comment: thank you, but your variable $path is never used. $path = $file?

Comment: check my edit - I used KernelInterface to locate your resource

Comment: Using your code, I get the following error message: "Bundle "App" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?" How come it is not recognized? Using the @App path works for rendering twig files in my views folder.

Comment: check my edit - you need to use ``Resources`` folder

Answer (score 0):

Taking help from Tomasz's answer here is another way to make it work, in this case it let's you read the files from asset directory. This works in Symfony 4 onward.

```
    //Imports used
    use Symfony\Component\Asset\Package;
    use Symfony\Component\Asset\VersionStrategy\EmptyVersionStrategy;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;


    $package = new Package(new EmptyVersionStrategy());
    $path = $package->getUrl('assets/pdf/pdffilename.pdf');
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->setContentDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
        "pdf-name-at-the-time-of-download.pdf"
    );

    return $response;
```